# Putting numbered chapter in TOC formatted as an unnumbered chapter

Tags: memoir

I am making a template for my PhD thesis, and have come across a short obstacle. It is customary to insert the scientific publications themselves into the thesis, and put a dedicated title page for each paper before it. I thought I would redefine `\chaptername` to indicate that a paper will follow. However, I do not want the "paper number" to appear in the table of contents. If I instead use a starred chapter and put `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Paper 1}`, then it appears correctly in the toc, but without the newly defined `chaptername` on the actual chapter page.

To be clear, I would like the entry "Paper 1" in the ToC to be formatted in the same way as "Ackknowledgements" is, i.e. without a number in front. But I would like that number to be present on the actual chapter page.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    
\tableofcontents

\chapterstyle{thatcher}

\frontmatter
\chapter{Acknowledgements}

\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Theory}
\lipsum[2]

\renewcommand*{\chaptername}{Paper}
\setcounter{chapter}{0}
\chapter[Paper 1]{Title of Paper 1}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? I don't quite follow what it is you want to do here. We normally make the article title pages separately (without the use of `\chapter` and then add whatever is need in the toc via `\addcontentsline` so I don't quite follow your need for `\chapter` in this case.

Comment: The reason I use \chapter here is so that I easily could maintain the same chapter style for the paper title pages. I added some more text to the question that I hope clarifies what I want to achieve. Keep in mind I am a latex novice, and simmingly simple, custom solutions are not that obvious to me ;)

Comment: Here is a very simple example, https://data.math.au.dk/publications/phd/2018/math-phd-2018-tnd.pdf of what we have dones. We have even more advanded examples among our other PhD thesises

Comment: I would not maintain the same style as this is not actually a chapter. One can of course do nasty things of locally disabling `\addcontentsline` but that is probably about it.

Comment: In your example, it seems to me that the paper title pages have the same style as the preceeding chapters. Regardless of what the "best practices is" from a purely typographical standpoint, is there a logical way of achieving what I asked? It seems you have done exactly that in the example posted above.

Comment: That example haven't used the chapter command

Comment: Feel free to share what was done in the example, then.