# Adjust page number in toc when adding manual titlingpage in memoir

Tags: memoir, page-numbering

I am writing up a template for my PhD thesis, and am making the title pages for the scientific publications to be included. Following daleif's recommendation from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/551216/putting-numbered-chapter-in-toc-formatted-as-an-unnumbered-chapter?noredirect=1#comment1392154_551216), I am using the `titlingpage` environment to do this, and then using `addcontentsline` to add it to the toc.

But the page number is reset to 1 in the toc. How can I make it continue the page counter used earlier?

MWE

```
\documentclass[openright]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    
    \tableofcontents
    
    
    \chapter{Introduction}
    \lipsum[1-3]
    
    \chapter{Methodology}
    \lipsum[4-6]
    
    \chapter{Results and Discussion}
    \lipsum[7-9]
        
    \chapter{Conclusion and Outlook}
    \lipsum[10]
    
    \cleardoublepage
    
    \begin{titlingpage}
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Custom Title Page}
        
        \centering
        \phantom{---}
        \vfill
        \scshape\Huge
        An Awesome Title Page
        \vfill
    \end{titlingpage}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Not at pc so cannot test. If remember correctly there is also a starred version of the env. But why is it at the end and not at the start?

Comment: We usually place a colored title page for each paper after the thesis itself, just before actually reprinting the published versions. The starred version fixed it! Thanks! The manual actually explicitly explains this, but I of course missed it...

Answer (score 0):

As daleif explained in the comments above, the starred version of `titlingpage` solves the problem:

```
\documentclass[openright]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    
    \tableofcontents
    
    
    \chapter{Introduction}
    \lipsum[1-3]
    
    \chapter{Methodology}
    \lipsum[4-6]
    
    \chapter{Results and Discussion}
    \lipsum[7-9]
        
    \chapter{Conclusion and Outlook}
    \lipsum[10]
    
    \cleardoublepage
    
    \begin{titlingpage*}
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Custom Title Page}
        
        \centering
        \phantom{---}
        \vfill
        \scshape\Huge
        An Awesome Title Page
        \vfill
    \end{titlingpage*}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]